# Problems with redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've just looked through a lot of pages to get a solution for my problem, but to now avail. The problem is extremely trivial. I have a web-page on my local server and if I write just "localhost" in browser, I see the folder structure, but I want to be redirected to index file (php). In other words, how to redirect from "localhost/" or "localhost" to "localhost/index.php"

Comment: which server (wamp/apache/IIS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your webserver is not configured correctly.

If you're using Apache you have to add `index.php` to `DirectoryIndex` in your config and restart it.